# How to check with php if ssl is supported with current curl extension installation?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Is it possible to check with php, whether ssl is supported with current curl extension installation to avoid this error http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#curl_1_SSL_is_disabled_https ? 
Which one of ways below is the correct way to go?

1)

```
if (stripos(curl_version()['ssl_version'], "openssl") !== false) {
```

2) check for bitmask with CURL_VERSION_SSL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if curl has support for ssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773516/how-to-check-if-curl-has-support-for-ssl)

Comment: I edited the question as it is not actually a duplicate.